# Showing a DIV within a hidden DIV using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hidden, slidedown, slideup

I have a main DIV which is hidden.  Within this main DIV i have a child DIV which is hidden.

I have a function which slides down the child DIV when a button is clicked, even though the parent is hidden.  When another button is clicked the main div shows and so does the child, exactly as I want it.

My problem arises when i try to hide the child DIV when the parent is hidden. When i try to slide up this child DIV and then show the parent DIV, the child DIV is still visible.

It works on `slideDown` but not `slideUp`

Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't jQuery actually remove the element from the DOM when you hide it?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you using jQuery's hide() and show() methods or something else? What prevents you from calling hide() on the child after you show the parent?

Comment: @ChristianWattengård: no, it's just set to `display: none`. http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: My bad... I've probably dreamed something again...

Comment: try to first show the parent element and then slideUp the child.

Comment: You guys are right, I looked everywhere before I posted the question and found nothing. After posting the question, I had a lightbulb moment, googled again and found out that if the element is hidden I have to hide() and not slideUp().  All working now.  Thanks again folks!